# How to validate login credentials on ADFS via POST request

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, adfs, e-signature

I have a requirement to build an E-Signature tool for a verification purposes in Salesforce (LWC, Apex). It's a simple two input field form where the user has to enter the username and password and based on the input some information is displayed.

Now the company uses SSO in conjunction with Active Directory Federation Service (ADFS).

Is it possible to craft a POST request and send it to a ADFS endpoint and check the validity of the login credentials based on the response?